# It's not the first time + someone do something

Tags: tense

I read this,

> It’s not the first time Biden has voiced this
>   Trump-is-terrible-but-Republicans-are-OK sentiment.

And I find this sentence structure almost always is that "... not the first time" connects verb present perfect tense but with some exceptions,

> I want to say this is not the first time I represented a witness in a
>   criminal case.

Is this a mistake? Or who can explain it to me why it should be perfect tense behind "be not the first time"?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *wrong*, but I would use the present perfect.

Comment: @Andrew What isn't wrong? I can hardly understand the question. for the second sentence, it can be either one: represented or have represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to say this is not the first time I represented a witness in a
> criminal case.

In my version of British English this is a mistake.

---

It could be

*I want to say this **is** not the first time I **have** represented a witness in a criminal case.*

or

*I want to say this **was** not the first time I **represented** a witness in a criminal case.*

---

The tenses in the original make the sentence ambiguous as well as stylistically poor and grammatically doubtful.

Answer (score 0):

"Not the first time" can be used in any tense.

> - If a future US president were to suspend *Habes Corpus* it would not be the first time this has been done.
> - When I leave home tomorrow, it will not be the fist time I have done so.
> - When Caesar crossed the Rubicon, it was not the first time this Roman law had been violated.

Comment: But all your 3 sentences are in "has/have or had" done style.

Comment: I should edit the question to "perfect tense".